# Can I develop for Android and iPhone with Adobe AIR if I don't care about the App Store?

Tags: android, iphone, air, cross-platform

As far as I understand, applications made with Adobe AIR have been blocked from the App Store. If I wanted to utilize AIR anyway to create a cross-platform app (for iPhone and Android) would it be possible to distribute the apps outside of the App Store?

I have very little experience with the iPhone, but I know that in Android you can turn on the ability to install applications from other sources than the Android Market. This would not be a problem in this case, where the target group is small and controlled. Is this also possible with the iPhone?

#### Update

It seems my basic idea that iPhone AIR apps are possible doesn't work. This is a quote from [Adobe's page about the iPhone packager](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/):

> At this time, we have ceased further
>   development of the Packager for
>   iPhone, and we plan to keep this
>   completed work in CS5 to demonstrate
>   the capabilities of the Flash Platform
>   to support multiple platforms and
>   devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no official support for third party markets. There are other stores but your users would have to jailbreak their handsets to access them. I've see estimates of around a million jailbroken phones, which limits your audience to about 1% of the total user base.

There are two official options other than the App Store: Ad Hoc and Enterprise. The former allows you to send copies to a maximum of 100 devices, and there are limits on how often you can add/remove devices from the list. It's really designed for beta testing.

[Enterprise](http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/enterprise/) is designed for distributing in house apps to your employees, but you need over 500 people to be eligible.

In short, there is no way to send a URL or file to your users and have them install the app that way.

Comment: So what your are saying is that the iPhone needs a market, it cannot install an app from a file in the file system or from a URL?

Comment: And to clarify: I am not targeting the general audience, but instead a known group of users who would not pay for the app when downloading (or pay at all for that matter). It would be perfectly OK to give them a URL or send the app in a mail.

Comment: You can install HTML5 based web apps without the Apple AppStore, but anything non-HTML, non-JS and non-CS based will not work on the iPhone - it doesn't support Flash or Adobe Air.  I work on primarily HTML5 only web apps for the iPhone, and I rarely come across serious limitations.

Comment: @Moo: Would those HTML5-apps be installable in any way on an Android phone? Or would it be possible to make a Android version based on the same resources, but packaged in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think AIR applications run on iPhones at all... The AIR support on Android is still in private beta.